# Modern alternative to gmvault for downloading .eml messages from Gmail account

Tags: email, backup, gmail

I am looking for software that will allow me to download all my mail from Gmail account, preferably in .eml format, that allows for periodical updates/syncing without re-downloading everything. The ability to upload the downloaded emails to another Gmail account is a bonus.

I would prefer to avoid using GUI-based mail clients for this, as I would like to be able to download new emails without the need to see my inbox. Ideally, it would be CLI cross-platform tool, although I would use it mostly on Linux.

Basically, I am looking for a modern alternative to [Gmvault](http://gmvault.org/) which I have used in the past, but it seems that the last version was released on March 31st, 2016. When I tried to authorize Gmvault for use with my Gmail account recently, Google displayed the following message:

> This app is blocked. This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.